# URL amigavel não funciona com https

Tags: php

Eu utilizo um `.htaccess` para utilizar url amigáveis.

Tudo funciona perfeitamente.

Mas, eu instalei um certificado SSL no meu dominio, tambem esta funcionando, o site todo.

Mas, quando digito alguma url, que não seja exatamente o nome do arquivo ou caminho do mesmo, ele nao funciona. Da pagina não encontrada

meu `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?dominio.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?secao=news&url=$1
```

Com HTTPS:

```
https://www.dominio.com.br/index.php -> Funciona
https://www.dominio.com.br/news.php -> Funciona
https://www.dominio.com.br/news/alguma-noticia-lala/ -> Não Funciona
```

Sem HTTPS:

```
http://www.dominio.com.br/index.php -> Funciona
http://www.dominio.com.br/news.php -> Funciona
http://www.dominio.com.br/news/alguma-noticia-lala/ -> Funciona
```

Alguma ajuda?

Obrigada

Answer (score 1):

Na sua [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) você fez assim:

```
^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
```

Mas na sua URL tem uma barra no final

```
https://www.dominio.com.br/news/alguma-noticia-lala/
```

A regex deveria ser assim `^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$`, exemplo:

```
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?secao=news&url=$1
```

O `/` faz reconhecer com barra no final e o `?` faz ele ser ao mesmo tempo opcional, ficando `/?`

Outra coisa, verifique se não tem nenhum outro `.htaccess` em outra pasta acima ou se não tem mais regras no seu atual `.htaccess`, pois as regras podem se conflitar.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
tente deixar seu .htaccess desta forma:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?secao=news&url=$1
```